# Child and parent simultaneous resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make simple picture resizer on my web. However I have got one problem. Everything works fine if I am trying to resize parent. But another story is when I am trying to also resize child.

Those are parts of my code:

```
var newElement2 = document.createElement('div');
            var newElement2Id = 'p'+prefix+i;
            newElementId = prefix+i;
            newElement.setAttribute('id',newElementId);
            newElement2.setAttribute('id',newElement2Id);
newElement.appendChild(newElement2);
            newElement2.style.position = 'absolute';
            newElement2.style.left = 0+"px";
            newElement2.style.top = 0+"px";
            newElement2.style.background = "#E6E6E6";
//........................//
var childs = dragDrop.El.childNodes;
                dragDrop.addMarkers(dragDrop.El,childs[1]);    
//..........................//
addMarkers: function(obj,extra){
            var width = parseInt($(obj).css('left'));
            var maxW = dragDrop.Elements[$(obj).attr('id')].MaxRight-width;
            var height = parseInt($(obj).css('top'));
            var maxH = dragDrop.Elements[$(obj).attr('id')].MaxBottom-height;
            $(obj).resizable(
            {
                minWidth:50,
                minHeight:50,
                maxWidth:maxW,
                maxHeight:maxH
            });
            if(extra!=null&&extra!=undefined)
            {
                $(extra).resizable(
                {
                    minWidth:50,
                    minHeight:50,
                    maxWidth:maxW,
                    maxHeight:maxH
                });
            }
        },
//...................................//
```

This is not a whole code. It is too long. I hope that it is enough to help.
So, the thing is when I am trying to resize child it doesn't want to. When I've changed the order of resize so first was child and then parent I wasn't able to resize anything.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you jsfiddle this so we can see it working please

Comment: No I've tried to, but I can't. However I hope that someone will find out what is going on. The rest is useless now but I can't extract it.

Comment: Glad you found an answer sebap. You should actually answer this question as yourself. Then accept it. This is how SO handles finding a solution to your own question. Alternatively you could delete the question.

Comment: I have changed it as you said. Sorry for problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use: resizeAlso parameter in resizable